# php mail() function taking too much time to execute on centos6 server

Tags: linux, php, centos6, shared-hosting, virtualmin

I have written a small code to check the speed of my server. BUt it takes almost 60 seconds to finish execution.

```
<?php


     $start=time();

     $to = "test@gmail.com";

     $subject = "This is subject";

     $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
     $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

     $header = "From:test@mydomain.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }

     $after=time();
     $total=$after-$start;
     echo "</br>";
     echo "Total execution time : ".$total." seconds";
?>
```

What maybe the reason? and how can I improve the execution time?
I already increased the memory limit in php.ini file.

Comment: And is it completely executed ? Do you receive the email ? Could you check your logs, there is maybe a blocking firewall, a error with the DNS or a usable message in apache log

Comment: @Dom: It was an issue with the sendmail service in the server. I installed postfix and now its way much faster. It was 60 seconds with sendmail..Now it takes just 1 second..

Comment: The best way to figure out why a script takes a long time is to use profiling or logging in the script. It is a programming question, not an email or linux question.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with sendmail mailserver. Installing postfix mailserver solved the issue.